# Switching stereo input between three stereo outputs

Tags: switches, audio

I have a circuit I'm designing which will switch a stereo audio input signal between a total of three possible outputs: 1 - Dry (i.e. the signal will go straight through without being effected), 2 - Effect A, 3 - Effect B.

What kind of switch would I need to achieve this with the minimal complexity? I was under the impression that I would need an on-on-on switch, but am a bit confused about all the possibilities. I bought a DP3T switch but am now unsure how to implement it. A lot of the advice online seems to be about mono guitar pickups, and that's not what I'm working with.

Incidentally I'm not looking for smooth dynamic switching that doesn't 'click' or anything like that.

Any help appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Should work. Or a rotary switch.

Comment: Do you actually mean you want the *output* to be selectable from 3 input sources: raw, effect1, effect2? And are effect1 and effect2 both stereo in/out boxes?

Comment: @Justme Excellent! Do you know how I would do this? I'm utterly baffled by the wiring.

Comment: @td127 Basically, I want to route a stereo sound source input through either 1. Effect A, 2. Effect B,  3. No effect (bypass). All of these three options would be connected to the stereo output, but only the one with the stereo input routed to it via the switch would be output.

Comment: "All three options would be connected to the stereo output".. how is that being done without a switch? Are you connecting dry, fx1 out, and fx2 out to three inputs of an external mixer and the output of the mixer is your final output?

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure you've got the right switch, it should have 8 contacts / terminals in two groups of 4. In each group of 4 there will be 3 input contacts (call them A,B & C) and one output which connects to each of the inputs in turn as the switch is operated.
I would draw you a nice diagram, but the schematic editor does not appear to have a 3 way switch, yet alone a double pole one so you will have to put up with a verbal description.
For the Right channel connect the signal to the inputs of both effects devices and to contact A of the switch. Connect the output of effect 1 to contact B and that of effect 2 to contact C. The common contact on the switch then goes on to the next stage in your system. Repeat this for the Left channel signal using the other half of your switch.
Note it is far better to common the inputs of the effects and select their outputs (or straight through) with the switch rather than switch the inputs and common the outputs.

- The open circuit inputs may pick up interference and feed it into the
  commoned outputs and thence into the following stage.
- The two commoned outputs may interfere with each other.
- In the straight through position the input signal would "see" the outputs of the effects and be loaded by them.

Comment: Thank you for indulging me with the very clear explanation! I think my problem lay in trying to use the below DP3T toggle switch which has only two groups of three contacts and which, although allegedly offering 2-pole on-on-on, is not suitable for this implementation. I'll use a side switch instead, with 2 x 4 contacts as you suggested.

![DP3T](https://www.electrokit.com/uploads/productimage/41011/41011891.jpg).

Comment: If you have room for it, a rotary switch is probably your best bet. Something like this  https://www.amazon.co.uk/2P3T-Position-Channael-Rotary-Switch/dp/B076YVL29D many similar are available from your favourite supplier.

Comment: Sadly the switch you show appears to be a 2P2T with, possibly, a central off position. Unfortunately not suitable for your task.